# left hand side in Java syntax

Tags: java

I am preparing Java grammar for my parser generator.
Noticed that statements like "(x) = 5 ;" where x is an "int" compile and execute correctly, but cannot see that Java Language Specification allows "(x)" as left hand side. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

The following part of the JLS should be the relevant one :

[15.8.5. Parenthesized Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.5)

> If the contained expression denotes a variable then the parenthesized
>   expression also denotes that variable.

Which means `(x)` is equivalent to `x`, `x` being an expression by itself.

Comment: Out of curiosity: The production for `Assignment` ( [15.26](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26) ) only supports `ExpressionName` on the left-hand side which does not expand into a parenthesized name. What am I missing ?

Comment: Given the above specification, `(x)` is probably just considered to be  `x` (a  regular _identifier_  ) at compile time.

Comment: It is obvious that (x) is treated by Java compiler as equivalent to x, but the published syntax does not allow this. In 15.26, LeftHandSide is defined as ExpressionName or FieldAccess (which contains a dot) or ArrayAccess (which contains index in square brackets). So the compiler clearly accepts something more than ExpressionName. I wonder what. Primary?

Comment: ExpressionName includes Identifier, `x` is an identifier, whatever the type of what it identifies is .So  `x` may be e.g of type `Object` , it will also work ( `(x) = null ` ).

Comment: My point is that the formal syntax in JLS does not exactly describe the language accepted by the compiler. Experiments show that the definition of LeftHandSide should be: ExpressionName or FieldAccess or ArrayAccess or ( LeftHandSide ). The meaning of that latter is well defined by the informal description in 15.8.5.